# Impossible to upload documents on folder of document libraries with custom path

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are connecting to a Sharepoint site having multiple document libraries. Some of the document libraries are created with a custom path. To do this we use the "url" property as described in the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcreationinformation_members.aspx).

As a result, the document libraries have following path in our Sharepoint site:

- /sites/customers/CUSTOM_PATH/DocLib1/
- /sites/customers/CUSTOM_PATH/DocLib2/
- /sites/customers/CUSTOM_PATH/DocLib3/
- ...

Those document libraries also have multiple folders.
When uploading a document, for instance, to the folder ABC of DocLib1, the documents are not uploaded to the ABC folder. Instead, we have new folders "DocLib1/ABC" being created in the document library.

To upload the document via the graph API we use following endpoint:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/**DRIVE_ID**/items/**ABC_FOLDER_ID**:/**FILE_NAME**:/createUploadSession

**Reproduction scenario:**

1. Create a document library DocLib1 using a custom URL path ( see URL property in https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcreationinformation_members.aspx).
2. Create a folder ABC in that document library
3. Upload a document to that folder using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/**DRIVE_ID**/items/**ABC_FOLDER_ID**:/**FILE_NAME**:/createUploadSession
4. Upload the document to the returned uploadUrl

**Expected result:** The document is uploaded in the ABC folder of document library DocLib1

**Actual result:** The document is uploaded in new folders "DocLib1/ABC" created in document library DocLib1

Did you face that issue before ? Are you aware of any workaround to go over it ?

Best regards,
Cyril.